# Let $I\subseteq R$ be an ideal of a ring $R$. For any $a\in R$, $l_{R/I}(a+I)=l_{R/I}(a)$

Tags: ring-theory

Let $I\subseteq R$ be an ideal of a ring $R$. For any $a\in R$, prove that
$$l_{R/I}(a+I)=l_{R/I}(a),$$
where $l_{R/I}(a+I)=\{r+I\in R/I:(r+I)(a+I)=I\}$.

In trying to prove this I have the following:
$l_{R/I}(a+I)=\{r+I\in R/I:(r+I)(a+I)=I\}=\{r+I\in R/I: ra+I=I\}=\{r+I\in R/I: ra\in I\}=l_{R/I}(a)$.

We notice that $l_{R/I}(a)=\{s+I\in R/I:(s+I)a=I\}$

Comment: Is "$\left\{r+I\in R/I:ra\in I\right\}$" the definition of $l_{R/I}(a)$? It seems $l_\ast$ means some sort of annihilator, but it would be better if you gave more info

Comment: We notice that $l_{R/I}(a)=\{s+I\in R/I:(s+I)a=I\}=\{s+I\in R/I:sa\in I\}$.

Comment: You have defined $l_{R/I}(a+I)$, but what is $l_{R/I}(a)$? The argument of the former is an element of $R/I$, while the latter's is from $R$, so it's not clear how one defines "$l_R(a)$" in general.